# Android - VectorXML notification icon color, SAMSUNG bug?

Tags: android, vector, colors, notifications

I try to use the **new VectorXML** for small icon into the **NotificationCompat.Builder**. On Nexus devices everything works fine and Android automatically tint the icon to the required color, mostly to white. But on Samsung (S5 with Android 6.0.1) the icon is never tinted. See screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Any idea why? It is an Samsung's implementation bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all,

the solution is to make the **base (fill) color white**, then "auto" tint works fine also on Samsung devices! ;)

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24"
        android:viewportHeight="24">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFF"
        android:pathData="M12,12m-8,0a8,8 0,1 1,16 0a8,8 0,1 1,-16 0"/>

</vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue in a Samsung device, and I was able to fix it by removing the `fillType` attribute in the vector file and setting the `fillColor` to #FFF.